# Execute several protractor scripts with different features & specs in paralell

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I have several tests that make a regression test set. The tests are not dependent from each other, but they take a long time to execute sequentially. I thought I could ***execute them in parallel, probably in 2 or 3 threads or instances***.

Spec files are **protractor-cucumber-jscript and features are gherkin**.

Once this is accomplished, I will execute through a Jenkins job.

Is this possible to set up using the protractor configuration file? I want to **execute different features and specs in each instance**.

I tried the following, unsuccessfully:

```
var featsLocation = 'features/';
var stepsLocation = 'steps/';

exports.config = {
        rootElement: 'html',
        chromeDriver: './srv/build/applications/chromedriver/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe',
        seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone.jar',
        params:{
            authURL:'', 
            login:{
                email:'',
                passw:''
            }
        },
        resultJsonOutputFile:'',
        getPageTimeout: 60000,
        allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
        maxSessions: 2,
        framework: 'custom',
        frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
        multiCapabilities:[
             {  
                 browserName: 'chrome',
                 chromeOptions:{
                     args:["--headless"]
                 },
                 name: 'CAPABILITY_1',
                 logName: 'LOGNAME1_USERNAME1_A',
                 shardTestFiles: false,
                 maxInstances: 1,
                 count: 1,
                 specs: [   featsLocation+'authenticateCSM.feature'
                            , featsLocation+'locationSearch.feature'
                        ]
             },{                  
                 browserName: 'chrome',
                 chromeOptions:{
                     args:["--headless"]
                 },
                 name: 'CAPABILITY_2',
                 logName: 'LOGNAME1_USERNAME2_B',
                 shardTestFiles: false,
                 maxInstances: 1,
                 count: 1,
                 specs: [   featsLocation+'authenticateCSM.feature'
                            , featsLocation+'shipmentErrors.feature'
                        ]
             }],

        onPrepare: function(){
            global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        },      
        baseUrl: '',
        cucumberOpts: {
            tags: '',
            require: [
                        './support/*.js'
                      , stepsLocation+'shipmentErrors/shipmentErrors.spec.js'
                      , stepsLocation+'locationSearch/locationSearch.spec.js'
                     ],
            monochrome: true,
            strict: true,
            plugin: "json"
        },
};
```

URL and other parameters are passed using package.json.

When executed, I do get two instances of the selenium driver each one executing a cucumber feature but only one feature is executed per browser.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the config file syntax... any clues how I should build it?

---

***UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE***

After some updates sugested by **yong**, config file looks like this:

```
var featsLocation = 'features/';
var stepsLocation = 'steps/';

exports.config = {
    rootElement: 'html',
    chromeDriver: 'C:\\srv\\build\\applications\\chromedriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe',
    seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone.jar',
    params: {
        authURL: '',
        login: {
            email: '',
            passw: ''
        }
    },
    resultJsonOutputFile: '',
    getPageTimeout: 60000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ["--headless"]
        },
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 2,
        count: 1,
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

        process.on('unhandledRejection', function (reason, pr) {
            console.log("Unhandled promise at:", pr, "Reason: ", reason);
        });

        global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    },

    specs: [
        featsLocation + 'authenticateCSM.feature',
        featsLocation + 'shipmentErrors.feature',
        featsLocation + 'locationSearch.feature'
    ],
    baseUrl: '',
    cucumberOpts: {
        tags: '',
        require: [
            './support/*.js',
            stepsLocation + 'shipmentErrors/shipmentErrors.spec.js',
            stepsLocation + 'locationSearch/locationSearch.spec.js'
        ],
        monochrome: true,
        strict: true,
        plugin: "json"
    },
};
```

What happens now, is:

- I get 2 instances of WebDriver (*This is ok*).
- A browser opens and    executes any feature, ignoring execution
  sequence in "specs" section    (***NOT OK***)
- When the browser completes execution of a feature, it    closes
  (***NOT OK***)
- Since the browser opens, executes feature, closes... this is not
  parallel execution (***NOT OK***)

So now, I have the following questions:

1. How to tell the browser to execute in a separated instance of WebDriver (authentic parallel execution)
2. How to tell each browser what feature it must execute
3. How to tell each browser to not close until all features assigned to
   it are executed
4. How to tell the browser what is the execution order?

Here'a a drawing of what I want to accomplish:
[image: Multiple DIFFERENT tests executing in parallel]

Comment: You want specs run in parallel and want them execute in order in "specs" section,  the both requirement are conflict.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I want to find out. How to write the config file in order to resolve that "conflict"(sic). So, I want to have two instances of webdriver executing, each one, a set of features with their respective specs, at the same time. How to accomplish this? Adding another "specs" array? How to tie them to their respective insance? You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Protractor Configuration file guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts), you can specify `specs` for each capabilities:

```
   * Example:
   * capabilities: {
   *   browserName: 'chrome',
   *   name: 'Unnamed Job',
   *   logName: 'Chrome - English',
   *   count: 1,
   *   shardTestFiles: false,
   *   maxInstances: 1,
   *   specs: ['spec/chromeOnlySpec.js'],
   *   exclude: ['spec/doNotRunInChromeSpec.js'],
   *   seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
   * }
```

You can try use `multiCapabilities` to add 2 capbilities with different `specs`:

```
multiCapabilities: [
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    logName: 'Chrome - Suite 1',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2,
    specs: ['suite 1 specs']
  },
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    logName: 'Firefox - Suite 2',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2,
    specs: ['suite 2 specs']
  }
]
```

I never practice this before, so I'm not sure it will meet your requirement.

I specied different `browserName` in capabilities in my above code example, you can try use same `browserName` when practice.

And I'm not sure the running result can be wrote into same file, all are waiting you to find out. You can try this package: [protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin) for HTML report.

Comment: Changed to "capabilities" to: `capabilities: {
   'browserName': '',
   'phantomjs.binary.path': '/srv/build/applications/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs.exe',
    chromeOptions:{
      args:["--headless"]
    },
    shardTestFiles: true,
       maxInstances: 2,
       count: 1,
       },`    But the problem now is that browsers execute features out of order and close browser on each one. Browsers must remain open until test is complete.